# ggplot2 - Ordering graph by weight value

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to generate a bar chart (using ggplot2) with location estimates data along the y axis and a basic count scale along the x axis. My data is structured like so:

```
  Data <- data.frame(locations = c("A","B","C","D"...), estimates = c(200, 300, 400, 200...)
```

I then used dplyr to arrange my data according to estimates

```
  library(dplyr)
  Data <- Data %>% arrange(estimates)
```

So then I run my ggplot2 code

```
  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(Data, aes(locations, weight = estimates))+
         geom_bar()+
         coord_flip()
```

But the resulting plot is such, the bars have not been ordered according to estimates.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point using `dplyr`. All you have to do is to order `estimates`, extract corresponding `locations` and pass it to `scale_x_discrete`, for example: `scale_x_discrete(limits = Data$locations[order(Data$estimates)])`

```
library(ggplot2)

 ggplot(Data, aes(locations, weight = estimates))+
         geom_bar()+
         coord_flip() +
         scale_x_discrete(limits = Data$locations[order(Data$estimates)])
```

[image]